# Tiles of new questions appear indented

Tags: bug

When I click on a new question notification (image 1), the tile initially appears indented (image 2), which looks a bit unmotivated to me. Only when I reload the page, the appearance is correct (image 3). I'm not sure if this a feature or a bug? I'm using Firefox 86.0 on a Win7-64 platform.

## Image 1

[image]

## Image 2

[image]

## Image 3

[image]